# error while running update environment in elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hi Could someone help with the following error on one of our elastic beanstalk application please.

```
ERROR   Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch: lipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:431) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:152) ... 7 more. Check snapshot logs for details.

    [Instance: i--------] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...xpectedly after launch: lipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:431) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:152) ... 7 more. Check snapshot logs for details. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/00run.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

This error occurs when running the following update command is run:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment \
--application-name app_name \
--environment-name --------- \
--version-label ------- \
--template-name ------- \
--region eu-west-1
```

Thanks

Comment: this is what I could have done to debug the issue. Get to the `ec2` instance (I hope you can find it out) and try to override your docker container [entry point](https://medium.com/@oprearocks/how-to-properly-override-the-entrypoint-using-docker-run-2e081e5feb9d) using command line. Now execute your entrypoint command to see the error. I hope this will help you to find out the issue.

Comment: Hi @RishikeshDarandale can you give me the docker run equivalent to CMD ["/usr/bin/java", "-jar", "/usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war", "--httpPort=8080"] please. The error appears to be related to the port 8080 already being used 

Thanks

Comment: First `ssh` to your `ec2` instance. Then figure out your exited container with `docker ps --all`. Once you have container name/id, then use below command to login to docker container `docker run -ti {container_name} /bin/bash`. Now once you are in to docker container, use your command `java -jar ...`. now you will be able to see the log messages on your terminal.

Comment: Did above helped you to find out the root cause?